# I have trouble with side menu and mid div

Tags: html, css

[image]

- When I click the Main course, it's showing Main course details.
- When I click the Soups, it's not showing Soups details - it's going up.

Comment: Please show some of  your code, so that we can debug it.

Comment: Show us the code that you tried so far.

Answer (score -1):

```
            <div class="clearfix">

                    <article id="section-1"><h3 class="page-title">Soups</h3>
                    <p class="woocommerce-result-count pull-left" style="margin-right:30px;">Showing 1&ndash;9 of 11 results</p>
                    <p class="mint-products-per-page pull-left">
                        <span>View: </span>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">18</a> / <a href="javascript:void(0);">36</a> / <a href="javascript:void(0);">All</a> </p>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="product_item_wrap">
                        <div class="product_item">
                            <div class="product_img">

                                <div class="product_buttons center">

                                    <a class="wish_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Description<br>
                                    You are previewing "Paradise", a premium HTML bootstrap template that will help you design
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/products1.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"><i class="fe icon_search"></i></a>
                                    <a class="add_to_cart_button" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i>
                                    </a>

                                    </div>
                                <img src="images/products1.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            <div class="product_description center">
                                <h4 class="product_title">Striped Pants</h4>
                                <div class="price">$105.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_item_wrap">
                        <div class="product_item">
                            <div class="product_img">
                                <div class="product_buttons center">
                                    <a class="wish_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Description<br>
                                    You are previewing "Paradise", a premium HTML bootstrap template that will help you design
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/products2.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"><i class="fe icon_search"></i></a>
                                    <a class="add_to_cart_button" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>                                      </div>
                                <img src="images/products2.jpg" alt="" />                                   </div>
                            <div class="product_description center">
                                <h4 class="product_title"><a href="product-page.html">Cargo Pants</a></h4>
                                <div class="price">$59.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_item_wrap">
                        <div class="product_item">
                            <div class="product_img">
                                <div class="product_buttons center">
                                    <a class="wish_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Description<br>
                                    You are previewing "Paradise", a premium HTML bootstrap template that will help you design
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/products3.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"><i class="fe icon_search"></i></a>
                                    <a class="add_to_cart_button" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>                                      </div>
                                <img src="images/products3.jpg" alt="" />                                   </div>
                            <div class="product_description center">
                                <h4 class="product_title"><a href="product-page.html">Cargo Pants</a></h4>
                                <div class="price">$59.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="product_item_wrap">
                        <div class="product_item">
                            <div class="product_img">
                                <div class="product_buttons center">
                                    <a class="wish_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Description<br>
                                    You are previewing "Paradise", a premium HTML bootstrap template that will help you design
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/products1.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"><i class="fe icon_search"></i></a>
                                    <a class="add_to_cart_button" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>                                      </div>
                                <img src="images/products1.jpg" alt="" />                                   </div>
                            <div class="product_description center">
                                <h4 class="product_title"><a href="product-page.html">Striped Pants</a></h4>
                                <div class="price">$105.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_item_wrap">
                        <div class="product_item">
                            <div class="product_img">
                                <div class="product_buttons center">
                                    <a class="wish_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Description<br>
                                    You are previewing "Paradise", a premium HTML bootstrap template that will help you design
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/products2.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"><i class="fe icon_search"></i></a>
                                    <a class="add_to_cart_button" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>                                      </div>
                                <img src="images/products2.jpg" alt="" />                                   </div>
                            <div class="product_description center">
                                <h4 class="product_title"><a href="product-page.html">Cargo Pants</a></h4>
                                <div class="price">$59.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_item_wrap">
                        <div class="product_item">
                            <div class="product_img">
                                <div class="product_buttons center">
                                    <a class="wish_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Description<br>
                                    You are previewing "Paradise", a premium HTML bootstrap template that will help you design
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/products3.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"><i class="fe icon_search"></i></a>
                                    <a class="add_to_cart_button" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>                                      </div>
                                <img src="images/products3.jpg" alt="" />                                   </div>
                            <div class="product_description center">
                                <h4 class="product_title"><a href="product-page.html">Cargo Pants</a></h4>
                                <div class="price">$59.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>




                <div class="clearfix">

                    <article id="section-2"><h3 class="page-title">Main Course</h3>
                    <p class="woocommerce-result-count pull-left" style="margin-right:30px;">Showing 1&ndash;9 of 11 results</p>


                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="product_item_wrap">
                        <div class="product_item">
                            <div class="product_img">

                                <div class="product_buttons center">

                                    <a class="wish_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Description<br>
                                    You are previewing "Paradise", a premium HTML bootstrap template that will help you design
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/products1.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"><i class="fe icon_search"></i></a>
                                    <a class="add_to_cart_button" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i>
                                    </a>

                                    </div>
                                <img src="images/products1.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            <div class="product_description center">
                                <h4 class="product_title">Striped Pants</h4>
                                <div class="price">$105.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_item_wrap">
                        <div class="product_item">
                            <div class="product_img">
                                <div class="product_buttons center">
                                    <a class="wish_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Description<br>
                                    You are previewing "Paradise", a premium HTML bootstrap template that will help you design
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/products2.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"><i class="fe icon_search"></i></a>
                                    <a class="add_to_cart_button" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>                                      </div>
                                <img src="images/products2.jpg" alt="" />                                   </div>
                            <div class="product_description center">
                                <h4 class="product_title"><a href="product-page.html">Cargo Pants</a></h4>
                                <div class="price">$59.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_item_wrap">
                        <div class="product_item">
                            <div class="product_img">
                                <div class="product_buttons center">
                                    <a class="wish_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Description<br>
                                    You are previewing "Paradise", a premium HTML bootstrap template that will help you design
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/products3.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"><i class="fe icon_search"></i></a>
                                    <a class="add_to_cart_button" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>                                      </div>
                                <img src="images/products3.jpg" alt="" />                                   </div>
                            <div class="product_description center">
                                <h4 class="product_title"><a href="product-page.html">Cargo Pants</a></h4>
                                <div class="price">$59.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="product_item_wrap">
                        <div class="product_item">
                            <div class="product_img">
                                <div class="product_buttons center">
                                    <a class="wish_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Description<br>
                                    You are previewing "Paradise", a premium HTML bootstrap template that will help you design
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/products1.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"><i class="fe icon_search"></i></a>
                                    <a class="add_to_cart_button" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>                                      </div>
                                <img src="images/products1.jpg" alt="" />                                   </div>
                            <div class="product_description center">
                                <h4 class="product_title"><a href="product-page.html">Striped Pants</a></h4>
                                <div class="price">$105.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_item_wrap">
                        <div class="product_item">
                            <div class="product_img">
                                <div class="product_buttons center">
                                    <a class="wish_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Description<br>
                                    You are previewing "Paradise", a premium HTML bootstrap template that will help you design
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/products2.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"><i class="fe icon_search"></i></a>
                                    <a class="add_to_cart_button" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>                                      </div>
                                <img src="images/products2.jpg" alt="" />                                   </div>
                            <div class="product_description center">
                                <h4 class="product_title"><a href="product-page.html">Cargo Pants</a></h4>
                                <div class="price">$59.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_item_wrap">
                        <div class="product_item">
                            <div class="product_img">
                                <div class="product_buttons center">
                                    <a class="wish_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Description<br>
                                    You are previewing "Paradise", a premium HTML bootstrap template that will help you design
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/products3.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gal]"><i class="fe icon_search"></i></a>
                                    <a class="add_to_cart_button" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>                                      </div>
                                <img src="images/products3.jpg" alt="" />                                   </div>
                            <div class="product_description center">
                                <h4 class="product_title"><a href="product-page.html">Cargo Pants</a></h4>
                                <div class="price">$59.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
```

Hi Here is the what i am using code

Comment: Could you please write code in run snippet or share snap which you exactly want?